# Add one billion seconds to DateTime object in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, object

I'm having a lot of trouble and no success in adding 1 billion seconds to a DateTime object (user input variable).

The user enters their date of birth (DOB) in format YYYY-m-d H:i:s. This is then converted to DateTime(). Then 1 billion seconds are added to the DOB. The output is to be the DOB + 1 billion seconds, in format YYYY-m-d H:i:s.

I can not work out how to do this, and haven't found any suitable examples from other posts which have solved this issue.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? There should be tons of examples out there to add a number of seconds to an existing `DateTime` instance

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime::add function  http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

```
$date = new DateTime(DOB);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT1000000000S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Comment: An excellent example of DateInterval usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (strtotime('1991-12-13 06:25:12') + 1000000000));
```

You can do it in one line of code. Convert your date using strtotime and add the seconds. It's weird to ask for `H:i:s` in a dob field though.

The output is `2023-08-21 09:11:52`  (double checked also through [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=13&m1=12&y1=1991&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=&h1=6&i1=25&s1=12&ah=&ai=&as=1000000000&rec=))

Answer (score 0):

Man, I always hated doing datetime logic. In my experience the easiest way to do this is to convert everything to Unix timestamp. I integers are easier to manipulate than DateTime object (though this mentality could be a hold over from #backintheday).

Do your logic would be something similar to the following:

```
$dob = strtotime('2018-1-1 12:00:00');
echo $dob;
echo  "\n";
$sum = ($dob + 1000000000);
echo date('r', $sum);
```

That should get you heading the way you want.

*Note be sure your machine is 64 bit, else dates after 2039 won't work due to the limits of 32 bit integers.